# Google cloud storage uploads staying in blobstore/datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a PHP-based GAE app that takes file uploads, and uses the special app engine handled upload URLs to have users upload files directly to google cloud storage engine. This works great, but I just noticed that for some reason every file that has ever been uploaded also shows up in Blobstore. This is true even of files that I have already deleted from the storage bucket in question. Furthermore, when I try to delete these files from blobstore, I get a message saying they could not be deleted. How can I delete this? I don't want to be billed for them.. Also how can I prevent this from happening?

Here is an image of the blobs: 
[image]

Comment: Update: it turns out the blobstore records are automatically created by gcloud-php's createUploadUrl procedure for uploading files directly to cloud storage. What I didn't notice is that the "Size" column is actually just an attribute on each blob, so these records aren't actually taking up tons and tons of space. I still would like to delete them, however, which I am still unable to do.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue which should be reported in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list). If you create an issue there you should see a quick response. It seems anomalous that you shouldn't be able to delete these.